# Loosening .htaccess file's RewriteRule(s) to also access URL without a trailing slash

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

My `.htaccess` file always requires URL with **trailing slash** such as:

```
http://localhost/menjaraz/webroot/about/
http://localhost/menjaraz/webroot/2013/03/21/you-are-my-heart-you-are-my-soul/
```

to work, otherwise a 404 error is fired.

I wish to loosen the rule(s) so that an URL without an **ending slash** will **also** do as well.

Excerpt

```
RewriteBase /menjaraz/webroot
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/$ index.php?page=$1
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$ index.php?a=$1&b=$2&c=$3&page=$4
```

How should I do that ? I'm not very comfortable neither with regex nor with mod_rewrite.

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the last slash optional using the `?`:

```
RewriteBase /menjaraz/webroot
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/?$ index.php?page=$1
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$ index.php?a=$1&b=$2&c=$3&page=$4
```

The `?` makes the character or group right before it optional. Because there's no trailing slash, you need to add a condition to make sure `index.php` doesn't get rewritten.